# can we control which directories trigger a `lein auto` cycle

Tags: leiningen

Can we elegantly control which directories trigger a `lein auto` cycle?
I might want a test run triggered whenever a resource file changes, or when a file under a custom source path or a under a `:java-source-paths` changes, and so on. Even trigger a cycle when the project file changes.

Last I checked I think there was no lead towards this, in the sample `project` file contained in the leiningen source. Since I like leiningen so much, I thought I would ask.

Comment: Also curious whether any keyboard input might trigger a recycle as well :-)

Comment: I have learned this actually comes from a plugin, https://github.com/weavejester/lein-auto/issues/6, will post an answer when I have one

Comment: You may also wish to check out test-refresh:   https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh    There is info here on limiting source paths:  https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh/issues/66